# Find the alphabetically first String using Java

Tags: java, string, loops, output, java.util.scanner

My professor asked me to create a solution for this code, and I cannot quite get a good output.
He asked me a couple things:

> 1. Ask the user to input a String value, the value "END", terminates the loop and the program and is not included in the calculation of Strings.
> 2. In the end, you should output which of the Strings that the user inputted is the String that comes alphabetically first. So for ex: if the user inputs "aac" and "aab", the "aab" comes first.
> 3. I have created the code, but at the end of the output it gives me the value "END" as the first alphabetically String for some reason, and I am kind of confused.

I do not know if the professor asked right or is it just me that doesn't understand it!

My code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ush1_NOTDONE {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a String value, the value \"END\" terminates the code");
        String word = sc.nextLine();

        final String SENTINEL = "END";

        String firstString = null;
        do {
            if(!word.equals(SENTINEL)) {
                System.out.println("Type a String value, the value \"END\" terminates the code");
                word = sc.nextLine();

                if(firstString == null || word.compareTo(firstString)<0 ){
                    firstString = word;
            }

        }}while(!(word.equals(SENTINEL)));

        System.out.println("First alphabetically string is: " + firstString);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid do-while for this. Instead, do assignment in the while condition (assignment in java returns a value).

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String word;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String first = null;
        
        while(!(word = sc.nextLine()).equals("END")) {
            if(first == null || word.compareTo(first) < 0) {
                first = word;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(first);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified it a bit it perfectly works!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Mark this as an accepted answer then :)